# history.pushState how can I get rid of get parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history, pushstate

I am using

```
  history.pushState('id','myTitle','myURL');
```

to manipulate the displayed URL and the history stack.
At some point I am pushing get parameters like so:

```
history.pushState('id','myTitle','?mySubLinkedStuff=hotSubLinkedStuff');
```

Now when I do

```
history.pushState('id','myTitle','#justSomeHashtag');
```

it produces http://example.com?mySubLinkedStuff=hotSubLinkedStuff#justSomeHashtag
I can also overwrite the value of mySubLinkedStuff but not seem to be able to get rif of it alltogether.

Desired result:

http://example.com#justSomeHashtag or http://example.com/#justSomeHashtag

and obviously I don't want to make the whole roundtrip over the server and I also want to avoid using absolute path or URL to keep the project portable.

Comment: If you write `history.pushState('id','title','http://example.com/#hash')` it doesn't work?

Comment: Should have mentioned that I want to avoid using absolute adressing due to project portability.
But You are right - absolute URLs work of course.
Question edited.

Comment: How about `'/#hash'` ?

Answer (score 0):

As NimrodArgov rightly remarked: overwriting existing get-parameter strings works if you 
push the full URL.
So for ensuring portability of the app (keep it usable on various domains) I did this:

```
history.statePush(document.location.origin + window.location.pathname + '#myHashValue');
```

Works perfectly well and fast.

Answer (score 0):

To push current address without GET parameters :

```
history.pushState("id", "myTitle", 
  location.protocol + "//" + location.host +
  location.pathname + location.hash
);
```

---

Other than that ;

To push a **hash** change I could do :

```
history.pushState("id", "myTitle", 
  location.protocol + "//" + location.host +
  location.pathname + location.search + "#myHashHere"
);
```

To push a **query** change I could do :

```
history.pushState("id", "myTitle", 
  location.protocol + "//" + location.host +
  location.pathname + "?my=query&over=here" + location.hash
);
```

※ Sorry I don’t have enough karma to just comment on [Max’s answer](/a/27025873/2236179)… :/